# How to create this kind of glitch/vhs effect in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: Part of the picture, the stripe in the middle is what i want to know how to achieve in photoshop]

The red and blue color is from the original picture.
The filter is called VHS in the app.

Is this stripe related to channels,distort or liquify?
I also tried stylize/wind, that is not i want.

Comment: Google algorithms working hard I see. This is probably 4th question related to some sort of glitch effects I've seen in a month.

Answer (score 1):

I think this tutorial would help you create it on Photoshop.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrV6hg0lWRM&t=8s